# What are the disadvantages of having an odd value as instruction length in bytes?

Tags: cpu-architecture

On a byte addressable machine having fixed instruction size of 24 bits(3 bytes), what can be the disadvantages of having 3 bytes sized instructions?

Answer (score 2):

An instruction can be split across cache-line or even page boundaries.  (Or on a simple CPU without cache, split across any power-of-2 sized bus width).

Instruction cache has to support unaligned fetch (unless you fetch in wider blocks and buffer before decode).

As a minor disadvantage, code pointers don't have their low bits guaranteed zero, so you don't have a spare bit to use for tagged pointers.

Comment: Code pointers could be 24-bit instruction word addressed. IBM did this for their experimental 40-bit instruction word ISA that was (data) byte/octet addressable. The instruction cache would be word addressed.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Interesting.  That's not quite a *pure* byte-addressable machine anymore, since you have pointers that aren't byte-based.  I'm not familiar with that ISA so thanks for mentioning it.